# Path error with capistrano deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, capistrano

Here are the 2 errors for command 'cap deploy' :

```
::err] fatal: could not create work tree dir '/vol/www/myapp/releases/20111030161222'.: Permission denied

failed: "env PATH=/home/aw/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin:/home/aw/.rvm/bin:/home/aw/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin:$PATH RUBY_VERSION=ruby-1.9.2-p136 GEM_HOME=/home/aw/.rvm/gems/ruby
-1.9.2-p136 GEM_PATH=/home/aw/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136 BUNDLE_PATH=/home/aw/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136 sh -c 'git clone -q git://github.com/myapp/myapp.git /vol/www/apps/myapp/releases/2
0111030161222 && cd /vol/www/apps/myapp/releases/20111030161222 && git checkout -q -b deploy 7daff6202fabf3b007625093c9147fe0c402305a && (echo 7daff6202fabf3b007625093c9147fe0c402305a > /v
ol/www/apps/myapp/releases/20111030161222/REVISION)'" on myhostIP
```

However "capify deploy:setup" was running without any error (/vol/www/myapp subdir was created).

Be noted that I am running win7 and does not have rvm installed on development pc. BTW is the ruby in the path above the copy on local development pc?

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you have write permissions on the target machine in `/vol/www/myapp/releases/` recursively.

Can be done with:

```
cd /vol/www/myapp
chmod -R u+w releases
```

Comment: Same error after chmod. Just noticed that "capify deploy:setup" was running without any error (/vol/www/myapp subdir was created). Not sure why deploy has permission error.

Comment: Is it really the exact same error, or did the directory change for which the permission was denied? If same error: Is the owner of the target directory the same as the user, with which you try to deploy?

Comment: It is the exactly same error. There may be something wrong with the deploy setup because "cap deploy:setup" was able to create myapp subdir under vol/www which means that the user has the right there. Not sure which causes the user right below /myapps disappearing when it comes to the deployment with "cap deploy".

Comment: Here is the output of ls -l : /vol/www$ drwxrwxr-x 4 root root 4096 2011-10-31 07:02

Comment: Here is the output of cap deploy:check : The following dependencies failed. Please check them and try again:
--> You do not have permissions to write to `/vol/www/myapp'. (myhostip)
--> You do not have permissions to write to `/vol/www/myapp/releases'. (myhostip)

Comment: Which user/group does the myapp directory belong to? And which user/group are using for deployment?